# Custom Post Types and archives

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I have a custom post type: cats

When I visit `http://mysite.com/cats` I see all of my cat posts displayed using the template file `archive-cats.php`

I filtered `getarchiveswhere` to only return posts from this custom post type.

I output `wp_get_archives` on the page and it correctly lists the months that have cat articles in them.

Now my problem... the archive links are like `http://mysite.com/2013/04` which results in a 404. None of them work.

My question... how do I get the archive links to point to something that will list that month's archives correctly?

I would think something like `http://mysite.com/cats/2013/04` would be best but I don't see how to get anything working, let alone that sort of url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the rewrite rules yourself. This code should work:

```
function prefix_this_add_rewrite_rules() {

    // Add day archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule( '/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?post_type=cats&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cats/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/?', 'index.php?post_type=cats&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]', 'top' );

    // Add month archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cats/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?','index.php?post_type=cats&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cats/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?', 'index.php?post_type=cats&year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]', 'top' );

    // Add year archive (and pagination)
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cats/([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?', 'index.php?post_type=cats&year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'cats/([0-9]{4})/?', 'index.php?post_type=cats&year=$matches[1]', 'top' );

}
```

If you do this in a plugin, you need to call this function upon activation (via register_activation_hook()), and then flush the rewrite rules. In a Theme, hook into after_switch_theme.

You can use this plugin to help you with the debugging effort: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/